# Spring: How not to register a bean as a candidate for its implemented interface

Tags: spring, kotlin

With Spring 5, I have this service written in Kotlin:

```
@Service
class IncidentBindService(
    @Autowired private val incidentBindRepository: IncidentBindRepository
)  
    // Implements the same methods as ...Repo by delegation.
    : IncidentBindRepository by incidentBindRepository
{
    ... some more methods
}
```

Which means that `IncidentBindService` will offer all methods of `IncidentBindDynamoRepository` (because I want to keep them accessible at the service level).

However, Springs registers this as a candidate for autowiring as `IncidentBindRepository`.

I only want Spring to register it as `IncidentBindService`. Otherwise, Spring detects the autowiring above as having 2 candidates.

**How can I do that?**

For now, I have just simply changed it to the specific implementation:

```
    @Autowired private val incidentBindRepository: IncidentBindDynamoRepository
```

But that's not too good for testability.

I tried `@NoRepositoryBean` but that did not help. I need something similar but generic and in the reversed way.

Comment: I think it's a bad design.  The service and repository should be separate.  The service HAS-A repository - composition.  Inheritance isn't appropriate.  The problem goes away if you stick to that.  If your intent is to make a data service you should do so.

Comment: @duffymo, actually this is not inheritance but delegation.  The class in the question HAS-A reference to `IncidentBindRepository`.  And the construct `IncidentBindRepository by incidentBindRepository` implements all methods in the repo interface by delegating them to `incidentBindRepository`.

Answer (score 0):

I also agree with @duffymo that this is something that you should definitely avoid. You are basically merging two layers of your application into a single one. Still, if you really think this is the best approach for your use case, one possible solution would be to annotate `IncidentBindDynamoRepository` with `@Primary` so that you help Spring deciding on which `IncidentBindRepository` to inject preferably. It is not what you wanted, but it is the only option I can think of.

Comment: @duffymo misinterpreted the code - it's composition, not inheritance.

Otherwise yes, it is mixing 2 layers, but that's on a request by a team, which otherwise normally just calls the repository and and gradually adds functionality to it. So separating it this way is actually an improvement.